# NodeJS: Stylesheet not loading due to unsupported mime type

Tags: node.js, express

I'm making an app with NodeJS and Express, and when I start the server I get the following error:

```js
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/style.css' because its MIME type 
('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Here's my directory tree:

```
app:
|-node-modules
|-index.js
|-package.json
|-package-lock.json
|-views
  |-index.html
|-public
  |-stylesheets
    |-style.css
```

Here's my index.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/views/index.html"));
});

app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);
console.log("Server Is Active At Port " + (process.env.port || 3000));
```

And here's my index.html and style.css:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Express App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
body{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Please note that I'm just testing to see if the site works, and this isn't the full code for the site.

Comment: you forgot the `here's my question` section

Comment: It worked, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

<s>You're not showing us the full picture - how are your styles being loaded? Presumably with a `<link>` tag you opted not to show us. Anyhow,</s> the `express.static` middleware should take care of setting the correct mime type. You <s>probably</s> aren't providing the correct path to the stylesheet.

Your style tag in your html should look something like this:

```
<!-- note the "/static" part at the beginning of the url -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/stylesheets/style.css" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm loading it in with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/stylesheets/style.css"/>. It's in the question now as well. It still doesn't work though, I don't know why

Comment: My answer still stands - I crossed out the irrelevant parts. You are using `/views/stylesheets/style.css` - it needs to be `/static/stylesheets/style.css`. If this solves your problem, make sure to click the check mark next to the answer so others know that this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing
`app.use('/public' , express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` instead of `app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`

After that in your html while linking to the css file you can write
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/stylesheets/style.css">`

Hope this solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. Define `path` like this:

```
const staticfiledir = path.join(__dirname,'../public')
```

Setup for static directories to serve

```
app.use(express.static(staticfiledir))
```